# Firebase project restored from Google Cloud Console shows 'This project has been recently deleted' error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I recently deleted my Firebase project but managed to successfully restore it using the Google Cloud Console. However, I'm encountering an issue when trying to open the project. The error message displayed is: "This project has been recently deleted. It can be undeleted from the Cloud console."

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COlC0.png)

I have already confirmed that the project has been restored and is visible in the Google Cloud Console. However, I'm unable to access it through Firebase.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

To troubleshoot the problem, I have tried the following steps without success:

-Changing browsers to ensure it's not a browser-specific issue.
-Disabling all browser extensions that might conflict with opening the project.
-Verifying that the project has been successfully restored in the Google Cloud Console.

Despite these efforts, the project remains inaccessible, displaying the error message: "This project has been recently deleted. It can be undeleted from the Cloud console."

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has any suggestions to resolve this problem, I would greatly appreciate your insights and assistance.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can see the project in Cloud Console and the data in Cloud Firestore, but get the same error in the Firebase Console as above. Watching this one and hoping for a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

After sending a support request to Google, I received this response:

> I understand that you already restored your project 'my-project', but
> you're still unable to access it.
>
> To give you an insight, it could possibly take a day or more before
> you can access the Firebase console after restoring a project.   When
> you restore a project within the 30-day period, some services have
> delays in restoring and you might need to wait some time for services
> to be restored.   Some resources, such as Cloud Storage or Pub/Sub
> resources, are deleted much sooner. These resources might not be fully
> recoverable even if you restore the project within the 30-day period.
>
> You may also check out this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects) for more information.

So far, the project has been restored, but I am still not seeing the Cloud Storage content.

I hope this helps a little. I guess it's just a waiting game.